Checking for an Inner product
I am sure this is really easy but I can’t see it!

Let $\langle\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,\rangle : \mathbb R^3\times\mathbb R
^3\to\mathbb R$ be given by the expression
$$\langle v,w\rangle = av_1w_1 + bv_2w_2 + cv_3w_3,$$
$a, b, c \in\mathbb R$. Show that $\langle\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,\rangle$ is an inner-product on $\mathbb R^3\times\mathbb R
^3$ if and only if $a$, $b$, $c$ are positive.

I am okay starting with $a$, $b$, $c$ are positive and proving it's an inner product, but what about the other way, i.e. assuming it's an inner product and proving that $a$, $b$, $c$  are positive?
Thanks for any help.

Easiest to start in the other direction - assume any one of a, b, c is non-positive and showing the resulting bilinear form can't be an inner product - that is, its either asymmetric or not positive-definite.

Hint: choose $v=w=e_1$ and see the definition of inner product. And please use Mathjax in your post.

Suppose $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is an inner product on $\mathbb R^3$. Then by definite positivity of the inner product, denoting $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^3$, we have that $\langle e_i, e_i \rangle > 0$ for $i = 1,2,3$. Thus
$$a = \langle e_1, e_1 \rangle > 0, b = \langle e_2, e_2 \rangle > 0, c = \langle e_3, e_3 \rangle > 0.$$

Thanks for the help,I think I get it!
